# How to save Session BLL's variables?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I wrote an asp.net website.
I have a BLL project (meaning dll type project) 
in which I want to save some data to be static for the **session**.

how can I do so? If i'll declare them static they will be static for the **application**.
Is there a way to avoid saving them in the asp.net session dictionary (I don't want to burden the site, it's in the BLL after all).

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The session is the right place to store this data.

To use it within the BLL you can abstract from session and create a UserStore of some kind, that hides the implementation. This can be injected via DI, possibly using an IoC Container.

A more simple approach is to pass in a reference to the current HttpContext or session either when you contruct the BLL object, or call the method. Ideally you would use the [abstractions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextwrapper.httpcontextwrapper%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) library to keep it testable.

Comment: +1, however, I would suggest avoiding direct reference to System.Web assembly in business layer. Using a custom abstraction such as UserStore is a better idea.

Comment: Yes agreed, I was just adding the bit about the abstractions lib as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HttpContext.Current.Session` property.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a Business Object to hold that data and assign to the session?

```
public class UserSettings 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
}

// Assign
HttpContext.Current.Session["UserSettings"] = 
    new UserSettings() {
        UserName = "Bruno Alexandre",
        UserId = 123,
        Company = "StackOverflow Inc.",
        CompanyId = 321
    };

// retrieval: check for nulls
UserSettings userSettings = 
    HttpContext.Current.Session["UserSettings"] == null ? null : (UserSettings)HttpContext.Current.Session["UserSettings"];

...

Save( DateTime.UtcNow, userSettings.UserId );
```

Answer (score 1):

What about refactoring your BLL in a way, that you can create one instance of some business entry object (business facade) per user session?

With that approach you don't need static data. You can save your data in class fields/properties.

You will store one instance per session in the ASP.NET session and your BLL is not aware of sessions at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a decent article for this: [Fast, Scalable, and Secure Session State Management for Your Web Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163730.aspx)

**Optimizing Serialization** (from the article linked above)

...

> When designing your session object model, avoid storing object types
>   in the session. Instead, only store primitive types in the session
>   dictionary and rebuild your business layer session objects on every
>   request based on the session data. This avoids the overhead of using
>   BinaryFormatter.

...